# NSFetchedResultsController Change Update - Collection View

Tags: ios, collections, nsfetchedresultscontroller, reloaddata

I have a CollectionView, and when I edit an exisiting cell

```
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {

        NSLog(@"change update");
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
```

The cell doe not update still unless i scroll / or nav back.

Change update is getting called as seen in the log

Comment: Give more details of the edit that triggers the change notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is what i needed to implement.

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```